# Objective-c : UIColor * exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, exception, uicolor

I am trying to store UIColor value in its object where UIColor is member of class.

When I try retrieve the value it throws error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CALayerArray set]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5394860'
```

.... Call stack at first throw:

```
_product.ProductTextColor = [self selectColor];

- (UIColor *)selectColor
{
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:(0.0/255) green:(204.0/255) blue:(51.0/255) alpha:1.0f];
}

ProductDetails *prod = [productList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
lblProductname.textColor = prod.ProductTextColor;
```

At last line I am trying to get value but its throwing the error.
where

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) UIColor *ProductTextColor;
```

is member of Product class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace declaration

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) UIColor *ProductTextColor;
```

with

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIColor *ProductTextColor;
```

Comment: Its still crashing but not showing error in Console .. is their any memory management issue because of retain

Comment: Crashing where? When you are setting color? Try to detect the line where the app is crashing

Comment: lblProductname.textColor = prod.ProductTextColor;
here its got crashing

Comment: Try to `NSLog(@"%@", prod); NSLog(@"%@", prod.ProductTextColor);` before that line. What is in output?

Comment: is it the problem that return type is (UIColor *) and I am returning UIcolor ? I debuged but it got crash without any message with NSLog too

Comment: No, your are returning color correctly. Try `NSLog(@"%@", productList);` before `ProductDetails *prod = [productList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`. What is the error?

Comment: thanks I changed the implementation and storing an index number which gets color on assignment ... sorry but this small thing was taking much time ... thanks alot for your help